# MenuFlyout in a ListView: which element has been clicked

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a ListView with a list of comments:

[image]

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Comments}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="{Binding User, Converter={StaticResource UsernameToBackgroundColorConverter}}"
                    Margin="0,5" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource FlyoutBase1}"
                    Holding="BorderCommento_Holding">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid Margin="5">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding User}"
                                       FontSize="20"
                                       Grid.Column="0"
                                       FontWeight="Bold"
                                       Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                       Text="{Binding DateTime}"
                                       FontSize="20"
                                       Grid.Column="1"
                                       Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,5"
                                       Text="{Binding Text}"
                                       FontSize="20"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment class:

```
public class Comment
{
    public Comment(String id, String user, String text, String date_time)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.User = user;
        this.Text = text;
        this.DateTime = date_time;
    }

    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string User { get; private set; }
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public string DateTime { get; private set; }
}
```

The Flyout menu that appears when holding on a comment is defined in Page.Resources:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <MenuFlyout x:Name="flyout1" x:Key="FlyoutBase1">
        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="ReportCommentFlyout" 
                        Text="{Binding User, Converter={StaticResource ReportOrDeleteComment}}" 
                        Click="ReportCommentFlyout_Click"/>
    </MenuFlyout>
</Page.Resources>
```

Now, in the ReportCommentFlyout_Click I need to know the comment Id that is being reported/deleted. 
How can I do it?

I've tried

```
string CommentId = ((Comment)e.OriginalSource).Id;
```

But the app crashes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app crashes because you cast e.OriginalSource to Comment and it doesn't work because it's not of that type. Usually, it's often safer to way to do this by using "as"

```
var comment = someObject as Comment;
if (comment != null)
{

....

}
```

Regarding your problem, have you tried

```
var menuFlyoutItem = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
if (menuFlyoutItem != null)
{
    var comment = menuFlyoutItem.DataContext as Comment;
    if (comment != null)
    {
        string CommentId = comment.Id;
    }
}
```